# Themekit Shopify - How to try/preview code before releasing online? (no localhost possible)

Tags: shopify, backend, liquid

I downloaded Themekit to be able to develop locally. 
I am now trying to test my code before releasing it.

Unfortunately, as a localhost is not possible with Shopify & Themekit, I don't know how to proceed. As I make some design, I need to see in real time what I'm doing... Did anyone face the same issue? Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Hook up your theme to a development shop you open for yourself using your partner account. That way you can test your theme out.

Comment: Can you please detail a little bit. I don't understand what I should do. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the perfect tool for what I needed: http://motifmate.com/
Hope it will help others!

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on David Lazar's answer : [Shopify's Development Store](https://help.shopify.com/partners/dashboard/development-stores)

From Shopify's documentation itself :

> As a Shopify Partner, you can create an unlimited number of
>   development stores. A development store is a free Shopify account that
>   comes with a couple of limitations. You can use a development store as
>   a portfolio site for your business, to test any themes or apps that
>   you create, or to set up a Shopify account for a client. Setting up a
>   development store and handing it off to a client gives you a monthly
>   recurring revenue share.